# Device Token Push Notifications

Tags: xcode, device, token

How do I  obtain the device token?
I am trying to add it and I can't seem to understand.
What do I need to do?
Where do I go?
What do I need to get this?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    // Tell Parse about the device token.
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken];
    // Subscribe to the global broadcast channel.
    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@""];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken {
    // Get a hex string from the device token with no spaces or < >

    NSString *deviceToken = [[[[_deviceToken description]
                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:` when your app launches, then the system calls back into your app via the `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` method (which you must implement).  The `newDeviceToken` variable will have the device token.

See the documentation for the [`UIApplication`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call this in app delegate.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
    (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | 
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Make sure app delegate has this function

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)_deviceToken {
// Get a hex string from the device token with no spaces or < >

NSString *deviceToken = [[[[_deviceToken description]
                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""] 
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""] 
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
```

}